# erro ao executar run-android com react-native

Tags: react, native

Bom, após conseguir executar o comando inicial e criar o projeto(react-native init ) e estando com meu emulador android rodando na maquina (Genymotion) porém ao executar run-android ele acusa esso erro :

````
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_211 contains a valid JDK installation.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 3m 16s
12 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 11 up-to-date
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A configuração do React Native é cheia de nuances. Por esse motivo, recomendo você refazer novamente as configurações utilizando a própria documentação do React Native. Segue o link da documentação: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started (Só não esqueça de selecionar o **React Native CLI Quickstart**).